# Why are there so many names for electronic components in eagle cad?

Tags: components, schematics

I was searching for a diode to add in my schematic diagram in eagle cad, and when I typed diode there were too many results. There were different codes for each diode.
Do they all function differently?
I have posted a photo of results below.
[image]

Comment: All these are different parts with different characteristics. Google few of them to get the idea.

Comment: Thank for your idea of googling.

Comment: Compare the attributes found in data sheets.  Depending on your application, several different ones might satisfy your need, but only you will know which ones are right for the circuit you are designing.

Comment: What might be the reason for obtaining a gazillion different results if you typed "car" at google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are different, but the differences may not matter depending on what you're using them for.

For example, the [1N4148](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf) is rated for 100V peak reverse voltage, while the [1N5400](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28007.pdf) is rated for only 50V. Are you expecting high reverse voltages for your diode? If so, then the 1n4148 would be the better choice out of these two.

Conversely, the 1N4148 is rated for 150mA average rectified forward current, while the 1N5400 is rated for 3A. Are you expecting very high currents? If so, then the 1N5400 is better for that purpose.

There will be tradeoffs between all of the diodes, and part of the "engineering" is choosing the right one. If you only need a general purpose, medium voltage medium current diode, then the 1N4004 is a reasonable choice.

Comment: to manage the tradeoffs, one has to know what is going to happen in the circuit in all conditions...

Comment: Another big reason for different values in the parts selector is because they are used to create the pcb. Eagle is not just a schematic creator/editor